# Auto delete tmp folder jboss-eap-6.2

Tags: jboss-eap-6

I am using jboss-eap-6.2 on windows with Spring Tool Suite.

After few server start - stop cycles, the size of tmp folder increases in GBs.

Is there any way to deal with this problem?
Like, tmp folder can be auto deleted?

I have tried below option by providing argument, but is not working:

-Djboss.vfs.cache=org.jboss.virtual.plugins.cache.IterableTimedVFSCache -Djboss.vfs.cache.TimedPolicyCaching.lifetime=1440

What can be done to get rid of tmp folder automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with JBoss EAP 6. This issue is fixed in JBoss EAP 6.4.x release. You can delete tmp folder manually or through script after shutting down server instance. Dont delete tmp directory when server is up.

Answer (score 0):

I used this `bat` script. You can launch it when the server is down. The script delete `tmp`, `data` and `log` folders.

```
@echo off
SET JBOSS_HOME= <HERE JBOSS HOME>
SET JBOSS_STANDALONE_DIR=%JBOSS_HOME%\standalone
rd /S /Q %JBOSS_STANDALONE_DIR%\tmp 
md %JBOSS_STANDALONE_DIR%\tmp
rd /S /Q %JBOSS_STANDALONE_DIR%\data 
md %JBOSS_STANDALONE_DIR%\data
rd /S /Q %JBOSS_STANDALONE_DIR%\log 
md %JBOSS_STANDALONE_DIR%\log
```